# Mentioning a user using a command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Now I was doing a random command called `!insult` to roast a person I tag with @
So my idea was going to write a message in discord chat such as
`!insult @Diz` and the bot would respond with `@Diz you're bad`
It's working fine with randomizing the "roasts" but I'm stuck on the @ part to tag that person I want.

If anyone could help me and knows a solution, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See: The expectation on SO is that the user asking a question not only does research to answer their own question but also shares that research, code attempts, and results. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Without doing this, you may start to get downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

To tag a user you can use `discord.User.mention` just like it says in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.mention)
For example, you can have something like

```
@bot.command()
async def test(user:discord.User):
  await bot.say(f"{user.mention} you're bad")
```

Comment: Thanks Tristo, that helped me, the exact command didn't work but I found a way,this is how it worked for me:                                                                                                          @bot.command()
async def insult(user:discord.User):
  await bot.say(random.choice(["%s blob." % user.mention]))